# Using arrays in C to print specific values

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads

I'm really new to C language. Needed some help on how to use Array to print out specific values as discussed below .

Here is my Array Declaration :

Here `guestArray` gets all the values of `tid`

```
long guestArray[10]= {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
int l = 0;
void *guest(void *threadid)
{
    long tid ;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    guestArray[l]= tid;
    l++;
}
```

`tid` has values from 1-10

But when I use the array in some other function it prints values other than `tid`

```
void *checkOut()
{
int j; 
for (j = 0 ;j<10;j++)
{
printf("Guest %d \n" , guestArray[j]);
}
```

Comment: Is that all you got? Especially your first fragment: it's not part of a loop, and you *are* only filling in element #0?

Comment: My bad I forgot to add the full code

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It seems that `l` is not known to your function `guest` and it is assigning `tid` to anywhere. This invokes undefined behavior and you will get anything, either expected or unexpected result.</strike>

Another problem is the return type of your function is `void *` but you are returning nothing from it. Your compiler should warn about this.

---

**EDITS:** As per the [link](http://codepad.org/Eo7KTFY9) given by OP;
You are using wrong specifier `%d` to print the value of `tid`. `%d` is used for `int` type but `tid` is of type `long int`. Using wrong specifier invokes **undefined behavior** and you will get anything, either expected or unexpected result. Use `%ld` for `lon` type.

### 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: http://codepad.org/Eo7KTFY9 Here's the entire code if you want to have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks man , I really appreciate your help . But I'm now really confused on the part that whatever changes I'm making I'm still getting the same output . I'm using putty though I know it sucks but could I get your email or something to show you my output